How do I position the "callout circle" lower?
I followed this post to "callout" an element in my equation. Now I also want to define an environment such that I have a circle, an upward arrow, and text above the arrow. Here's my modification:
\documentclass[8pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%%%% Original downward callout
\def\calloutsym{%
  \ensurestackMath{%
  \scalebox{1.7}{\color{red}\stackunder[0pt]{\bigcirc}{\downarrow}}}%
}
\newcommand\callouttext[1]{%
  \def\stacktype{S}\renewcommand\useanchorwidth{T}\stackText%
  \stackunder{\calloutsym}{\scriptsize\Longstack{#1}}\stackMath%
}
\newcommand\callout[3][1.5pt]{%
  \def\stacktype{L}\stackMath\stackunder[#1]{#2}{\callouttext{#3}}%
}


%%%%%% My attempted upward callout
\def\calloutsymu{%
  \ensurestackMath{%
  \scalebox{1.7}{\color{red}\stackon[0pt]{\bigcirc}{\uparrow}}}%
}
\newcommand\callouttextu[1]{%
  \def\stacktype{S}\renewcommand\useanchorwidth{T}\stackText%
  \stackon{\calloutsymu}{\scriptsize\Longstack{#1}}\stackMath%
}
\newcommand\calloutu[3][1.5pt]{%
  \def\stacktype{L}\stackMath\stackon[#1]{#2}{\callouttextu{#3}}%
}

%%%%% A slide
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{align*}
k_{t+1}=\psi(A,\callout{\omega}{\text{marriage quality, evolves as a first-order Markov $\Pi_{\omega}$}})\tau_{H,t}^{\delta_{H,A}}\tau_{W,t}^{\delta_{W,A}} k_t^{\delta_{k,A}}e^{\calloutu{\xi_t}{\text{Technology shock, $\xi_t\sim N(0,\sigma_{\xi}^2)$}}}
\end{align*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}

However, the results I got is not exactly what I wanted. I want the circle to be positioned lower. What went wrong?


Try \newcommand\calloutu[3][-1.5pt]{%.

@HasanBasriÇetin Good catch. Thank you so much!
